# How to display (output) the number of iterations that were necessary to find a value in a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: java, iteration, binary-search-tree

I've written this program to create a BST, the user can create a tree,as well as search for a value in the BST but I need help to output the number of iterations that were needed to find this number and I don't know how.
I've created a variable "iterations" but I 'm stuck as how to create a method to collect this number. Any ideas how to implement this in my program, how to find that number and print it?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;  


 /* Class Node */
 class Node  


{
 Node left, right;
 int data;



 /* Constructor */
 public Node(int n)
 {
     left = null;
     right = null;
     data = n;
 }         

/* Function to get data from node */
public int getData() 
{
    return data;
}

/* Function to get left node */
public Node getLeft() 
{
    return left;
}

  /* Function to get right node */
public Node getRight()
{
    return right;
}
}

/* Class BST */
class BST

{

 private Node root;
 private int iterations;
 /* Constructor */
 public BST()
 {
     root = null;
 }
 /* Functions to insert data */
 public void insert(int data)
 {
     root = insert(root, data);
 }
 /* Function to insert data recursively */
 private Node insert(Node node, int data)
 {
     if (node == null)
         node = new Node(data);
     else
     {
         if (data <= node.data)
             node.left = insert(node.left, data);
         else
             node.right = insert(node.right, data);
     }
     return node;
 }


  /* Functions to search for an element */
public boolean search(int val) 
{
    iterations=0;
    iterations++;
    return search(root, val);
}



/* Function to search for an element recursively */
private boolean search(Node r, int val) 
{
    iterations=0;
    boolean found = false;
    while ((r != null) && !found) 
    {
        int rval = r.getData();
        if (val < rval){
            r = r.getLeft();
        }

        else if (val > rval){   
            r = r.getRight();
        }

        else 
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        found = search(r, val);

    }

    return found;
}

  public int getLastIterationCount(){
return iterations;
 }

 }
 /* Class LinkedListBST */
 public class LinkedListBST
 {


 public static void main(String[] args)

 {  


     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     /* Creating object of BST */
     BST bst = new BST(); 
     System.out.println("Linked List Binary Search Tree Test\n");          
     char ch;
     /*  Accept input  */
     do    
     {
         System.out.println("Enter integer element to insert");
         bst.insert( scan.nextInt() );                     



         System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue (Type y or n) \n");
         ch = scan.next().charAt(0);  


     } while (ch == 'Y'|| ch == 'y');   
     System.out.println("\nEnter an element to be searched: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Search result : " + bst.search(sc.nextInt()));

    System.out.println(getLastIterationCount()); //ISSUE IS HERE

    sc.close();

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a global int variable called `iterations` that is initially zero.

Then, in the loop of every method you have, increment `iterations`. At the beginning of every method, you'll have to reset `iterations` to zero.

Then, write a method called `getLastIterationCount` that returns iterations:

```
public int getLastIterationCount(){
    return iterations;
}
```

When you want to find out how many iterations were used, call `getIterationCount()` and print the result. For example, to see how many iterations preorder() takes, write this:

```
preorder(...);
System.out.println(bst.getLastIterationCount());
```

Here is what your BST class might look like:

```
/* Class BST */
class BST
{
 private Node root;
 private int iterations;

... 

  /* Functions to search for an element */
public boolean search(int val) 
{
    iterations=0;
    iterations++;
    return search(root, val);
}

/* Function to search for an element recursively */
private boolean search(Node r, int val) 
{
    iterations=0;
    ...
    return found;
}

public int getLastIterationCount(){
    return iterations;
}

}
```

Comment: The thing is that I want it just for the search method not for the 3 type of order. I've tried to do as you advised but my iterations number stays at 0 no matter what. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the code you have tried? I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I've edited my program in the question section and I've erased the orders methods, so I just need help on how to implement the iteration method to print the number of iterations the search needs to find a value.

Comment: I added a getLastIterationCount() method and indicated where you should declare the iterations variable in my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I've changed my program (see above) and deleted all the orders method (which I don't really need). So I don't know where to add the 'getLastInterationCount' method and where to make the iterations (see my code above).Thank you so much

Comment: Your code so far looks really good. You incremented and reset iterations in all the right places. I edited my answer to show the full structure of the BST class including iterations and getLastIterationCount(). I did notice that you print out iterations inside your search() method, which is great. If that does what you want it to do, you can make iterations a local var in search() and get rid of the getLastIterationCount() method entirely. Is there anything else I can clarify for you?

Comment: Your code so far looks really good. You incremented and reset iterations in all the right places. I edited my answer to show the full structure of the BST class including iterations and getLastIterationCount(). I did notice that you print out iterations inside your search() method, which is great. If that does what you want it to do, you can make iterations a local var in search() and get rid of the getLastIterationCount() method entirely. Is there anything else I can clarify for you?

Comment: Thank you for this help. I've edited the code in the question section to reflect what you advised me to do but now I don't know where to insert 'System.out.println(getLastIterationCount());'

Comment: It's already there in your main() method. It's correct, you've got it already.

Comment: Yes I know, but it doesn't work (cannot even compile), Netbeans signals an error, it doesn't recognize this method, so maybe the method is not positioned at the right place.

Comment: Please post the exact error you're getting and indicate which line it refers to.

Comment: I've updated the program in the question section, so at the end of the program I've included an output that Netbeans underlined as "Cannot find symbol-Assign return value to new variable" When compiling with the error and inserting element in BST then searching for the element, there is a runtime error : "xception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
 at javaapplication19.LinkedListBST.main(LinkedListBST.java:164)
/Users/hackmast/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED"

Answer (score 0):

Define a helper class called `SearchResult` which contains two members: `found` and `iterations`.

Have your `search(..)` method return this class, instead of `boolean`.

Comment: Never used the helper class before so I don't know how to implement them.

Comment: It's just another class you write that you then use in your main class.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to do that. I need help for this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to to set up the iterations=1 then increment later on and print out using 'bst.getLastIterationCount()' and not 'getLastIterationCount()' since the method is in the bst class.

Comment: Did my answer help you figure this out? If so, please consider accepting it so others can find it who have the same problem.

Comment: You're welcome! If your question is answered, please accept an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks!